# Python : update an initialized dictionary with new lists as value for each key

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, updates, key-value

I have an initialized dictionary like:

```
nemas = {'PERSON' : '', 'ORGANIZATION':'' , 'LOCATION': ''}
```

and three lists of names :

```
 person_names =    [u'Albert Einstein', u'Hermann Einstein', u'Pauline Koch', u'Einstein', u'Jakob']
organization_names = [u'Elektrotechnische Fabrik J. Einstein & Cie']
location_names =  [u'Ulm', u'Kingdom of Britain', u'Munich']
```

I intend to update the dictionary and get:

```
names = { 'PERSON' : [u'Albert Einstein', u'Hermann Einstein', u'Pauline Koch', u'Einstein', u'Jakob'], 
'ORGANIZATION': [u'Elektrotechnische Fabrik J. Einstein & Cie'], 
'LOCATION': [u'Ulm', u'Kingdom of Britain', u'Munich']  }
```

I tried :

```
name_dict = {"PERSON":dict(person_names), "ORGANIZATION": dict(organization_names), "LOCATION":dict(locatoin_names)}
print(names.update(name_dict))
```

but it didn't work. Is there any Pythonic way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your first dictionary gives a syntax error.

Comment: `nemas = {'PERSON' : , 'ORGANIZATION': , 'LOCATION': }` is not valid python...

Comment: I corrected it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we ignore your first line:

`nemas = {'PERSON' : , 'ORGANIZATION': , 'LOCATION': }`

You simply can't do that. However you could do

```
nemas = {'PERSON' : None, 'ORGANIZATION': None, 'LOCATION': None}
```

Then in the end what you want is a dictionary of lists but you try to make a dict of dicts. Try this:

```
name_dict = {"PERSON":person_names, "ORGANIZATION": organization_names, "LOCATION":location_names}
```

Please note that I fixed some typos.
Then you can get the expected output by

```
print(name_dict)
```